# JavaScript RegExp isn't matching the correct group

Tags: javascript, regex

This regular expression: `/\{(\w+)\}/g` returns `["{name}", "{color}"]` and ignores my parenthesis around `(\w+)`

Why doesn't this work? What is the correct regular expression?

---

**Token replacement:**

```
const item = {
  name: 'foo',
  color: 'bar'
};

let str = `'{name} - {color}'`

console.log( str.match( /\{(\w+)\}/g ) );
```

Comment: The answer is to use exec, not match, apparently

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c6dsgknc/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you